# Using BFD with MinGW

Tags: c++, mingw

i actually trying to compile an application that uses bfd library (a part of binutils) using MinGW. I've added the libiconv 1.13 and gettext 0.17 packages to my MinGW directory. If i compile my source including bfd:

```
$ g++ iftest.cpp -o iftest -llibiconv -lbfd -liberty
```

This leads to the following linkage error:

```
c:/binrev/development/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.5/../../../libbfd.a(libbfd.o):libbfd.c:(.text+0x6ee): undefined reference to `libintl_dgettext'
c:/binrev/development/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.5/../../../libbfd.a(libbfd.o):libbfd.c:(.text+0x740): undefined reference to `libintl_dgettext'
c:/binrev/development/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.5/../../../libbfd.a(libbfd.o):libbfd.c:(.text+0x79b): undefined reference to `libintl_dgettext'
c:/binrev/development/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.5/../../../libbfd.a(libbfd.o):libbfd.c:(.text+0x7d0): undefined reference to `libintl_dgettext'
c:/binrev/development/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.5/../../../libbfd.a(bfd.o):bfd.c:(.text+0x8fd): undefined reference to `libintl_dgettext'
c:/binrev/development/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.5/../../../libbfd.a(bfd.o):bfd.c:(.text+0x964): more undefined references to `libintl_dgettext' follow
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why have you tagged this as C#? At a wild guess, you need a library called libintl.

Answer (score 1):

Have you also added [libintl](http://www.xs4all.nl/~waterlan/libintl.html)?  If you don't need relocation (provided by the patched version I've pointed to), I believe it comes as part of the `gettext package.